# object neo4j is not a member of package org

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I am trying to read data from neo4j using spark job. The import itself is showing this error. I tried to import org.neo4j.spark._ in intellij IDEA, but it is showing an error "Cannot resolve symbol spark". While trying in the spark-shell, it is throwing an error,

":23: error: object neo4j is not a member of package org
import org.neo4j.spark._"

Spark version - 3.1.1

dependencies
[image]

Comment: `org.neo4j:neo4j` and `org.neo4j:neo4j-bolt` are only useful if you are running Neo4j server in the same process as your application. Isn't your Neo4j server hosted separately (locally via Neo4j Desktop or Docker) or remotely?

Comment: I need to test it by running locally - @fbiville

Comment: If you do not need to embed Neo4j to your application, you should remove the neo4j and the neo4j-bolt dependencies. Start a Neo4j instance with Docker or Neo4j Desktop instead.

Comment: Then how do get the data in the shell ? I tried the import org.neo4j.spark._ but showing an error. I am new to Spark, its confusing.